# cdebootstrap vs debootstrap: what is the difference?

Tags: debootstrap

Does `cdebootstrap` provide any advantages to `debootstrap`? What is the difference between the two other than the implementation language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debootstrap` and `cdebootstrap` offer largely similar sets of functionalities; they can install Debian and certain derivatives, in one of three flavours (standard, *i.e.* a base Debian installation; minimal, *i.e.* only `apt` and essential packages; and build-oriented, *i.e.* `build-essential` and its dependencies). They both also support foreign installations, *i.e.* installations with a different architecture than the host architecture (using QEMU for emulation).

The differences are the implementation language, the configuration language, and the supported derivatives (Kali for `cdebootstrap`, Tanglu for `debootstrap`; both support Ubuntu). The configuration language is the most significant difference for users; I find the `cdebootstrap` setup simpler, but the `debootstrap` setup has the advantage of being more explicit (with full package lists).